# Low Quality post shows as "Review completed" with all "Delete" votes, but it's not deleted?

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts, vote-to-delete

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/2044799#./2044799?&_suid=1367592782329019465020802307697) currently shows "**Review completed** 21 mins ago" with one "Delete" vote and five "Recommend Deletion" votes.

[image]

However, [the answer is still visible on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16361120/334849); how can the review be completed with all "Delete" votes, yet the answer remains undeleted?

**EDIT:** This was finally deleted by a moderator, but my question still stands: what's going on here?

**EDIT 2:**  Looks like this just [happened again](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/2239320) (six "Recommend Deletion" votes, but it's still around), so whatever it is, it's still going on.

Comment: That "delete" is a bit strange too, no-one except mods can cast an actual delete vote on an answer with >= 0 score.

Comment: "Recommend Deletion" only raises the posts score in the delete queue, not actually delete it. Since this question has a score of greater than -1 only a moderator will be able to delete it.

Comment: @Seth -- Interesting.  I would have expected a completed review with all Delete votes to, you know, *delete* the answer.  It appears that my understanding of the Low Quality review queue may be flawed.

Comment: Retagging this as a bug. This is definitely not the case before. Anything with 6 delete or recommend delete votes is nuked - regardless of votes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** we've added a new post history entry for such questions, which should make this less confusing for *future* review-deletions:

[image: Post Deleted From Review]

---

[The post history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16888245/revisions) tells the story: it *was* deleted after the review was completed... And then the author undeleted it.

This is possible on any post where less than *threshold* users actually cast delete votes (where *threshold* is 3 for answers) - in other words, every post deleted because the Low Quality review completed, rather than every post that was deleted by 20K+ users or moderators thus completing the review.

See, the checks that normally prevent authors from undeleting community-deleted posts depend on a check that runs against the users recorded in the post history entry for the deletion...

...and there's no post history entry created for Low Quality Review-deleted posts.

There are currently 124 posts on Stack Overflow that were deleted in response to LQ reviews, and then later undeleted by their authors. Note that 76 of these were edited by their authors - and 22 of *those* were later up-voted or accepted (by someone other than the author)!

Comment: I still think we should track who voted to delete or recommended deletion and show the usernames on the "deleted by" line just as we do with regularly deleted posts. Not sure if there are any technical snags with doing that though.

Comment: Seems like it should be possible; let's ask Emmett tomorrow.

Comment: I vaguely recall there was *a* reason why we don't do it, but not what it is. Selective memory is selective.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense, thanks for such a detailed answer (although the answer still surprises me!).  I agree with Anna, it's a little odd to look at the history and see "Post Undeleted", and not see a corresponding "Post Deleted" entry.

Comment: @Anna and shog, any update? Emmett no longer works for SE so does it mean showing the usernames is doomed?

Comment: @ShadowWizard We do have other developers... :) No update, though I still think this is worth exploring.

Comment: Good to know that, @Anna! :D If and when there will be update, can you please update [this answer of yours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184568/152859) as well? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'll do my best to remember to do that. :)

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213347/does-review-activity-appear-in-a-questions-timeline-if-not-it-should), @Sha

Comment: Thanks shog and @Anna don't worry, I'm known for nudging the team from time to time so I'll make sure you don't forget. ;)