# Answer isn't deleted even after 7 people recommending deletion

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, review, low-quality-posts

I reviewed an answer in the Low Quality queue yesterday and chose "Recommend deletion", but it doesn't seem to have done anything other than adding the autocomment. Other than the comment there's no evidence of review ever happening.

The review was completed with 7 people recommending deletion but the answer is still there<s>, which suggests that no-one managed to flag it</s>.

- [The answer itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17432967/502381)
- [Review history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/2429265)

The review action doesn't show up in [my history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502381/juhana?tab=activity&sort=all), only the autocomment is there:

[image: No review action]

<s>The flag is not in my flag history</s> (edit: and apparently it shouldn't be).

[image: Not in flag history]

What's going on?

Comment: I think "Recommend deletion" <> "Flag". If I'm not wrong, I remember doing both in a question.

Comment: But I have no idea why the 7 recommend deletion votes have not managed to delete the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Recommend Deletion is a review-only action that will automatically delete a post once so many users have also recommended deletion. It does *not* cast a flag for moderation attention, and shouldn't. The whole point of that option is to allow users to handle the deletion of the post themselves so moderators don't have to be involved.

<s>As for it not being deleted, that *would* be a bug. The only thing I see different about this one (not deleted) versus those that are actually being deleted is that it has seven Recommend Deletion votes (whereas it only takes six to delete).</s>

**Update:** It appears it *was* deleted, and the OP was able to [undelete the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17432967/revisions).

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to reflect the actual bug.

Comment: @Juhana: Apparently the OP is able to undelete... Makes me wonder how many posts deleted by that queue just got undeleted in the exact same state.

Comment: Isn’t deletion supposed to show up in the revision history, too?

Comment: It doesn't if there's no user to attribute it to, apparently.

Comment: Well, that used to be Community ♦, which would stop it from getting undeleted. It looks nicer without Community ♦, and is also very broken. Yay.

Comment: @minitechη: I believe they've always been silently deleted by no one. You're probably thinking of automatic deletions due to age / inactivity / down-votes, which I do believe get deleted by Community.

Comment: @minitechη for what it's worth, I noticed this lack of revision [and reported it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184566/152859). :)