# Answer is shown as having a undelete vote when there aren't any pending votes

Tags: bug, deleted-answers

[This answer on Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/81824/199) is deleted, and it shows a pending undelete vote, but there isn't any pending vote to undelete it.

> [image: screenshot]

What happened is the following:

- The author of the answer deleted it
- The same user undeleted it
- From the review queue, [6 different users suggested to delete it](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/17873)

> [image: screenshot]

There isn't any undelete vote. It is also not true that the answer has been deleted from the owner.

Comment: [Probably related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184566/152859). There is no revision item for deletion via Review, and no record who actually deleted it i.e. the six users recommending deletion, so probably the system is just taking the last one who cast an actual delete vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, delete and undelete votes do not show up in our fancy timeline like reopen and close votes do for questions. I've looked over several example questions on SO (just using the delete tab in the 10k tools), and all questions I have looked at that have pending votes, or had been previously deleted and/or undeleted, do not have *any* votes listed in the timeline. The only thing that appears is the **history** event when a deletion or undeletion actually occurs on the post.

So in all likelihood, there probably *is* a pending undelete vote on that answer.

As for the "deleted by owner" bug, this is already known. The same issue occurs when an owner had previously deleted (and then undeleted) an answer, and then the question gets later deleted, such as [with migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108954/previously-deleted-answers-on-migrated-questions-retain-user-who-deleted-them-b).

Comment: As for "delete and undelete votes do not show up in our fancy timeline," [the timeline shows when an answer is deleted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sqeE5.png).

Comment: @kiamlaluno I'm aware, but it does not now show the *votes* themselves. Only the final events.