# Can't flag an answer again because it'is deleted and un-deleted by the author

Tags: support, flags

I flagged and voted to delete a [low quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19673757/1009479)

After a while, the flag was deemed helpful, but the answer isn't deleted by moderator. Turns out the author deleted the answer which cleared the flag and delete vote status automatically, and then he un-deleted the answer. Now I can vote to delete again, but I can't flag it anymore because I already flagged it before.

Does this need to be fixed or is it by design?

---

**EDIT**: the answer is modified after I asked this question, now its quality is fine, but my question remains.

Comment: Since you can't flag it again it means the flag has not been cleared. It takes a few flags(i think its 5 or 6) for the answer to get deleted or a 10K+ users 3 votes. What do you mean by `Now I can vote to delete again`? How? What are your UI options?

Comment: @mehow My flag is deemed helpful already, but the post is not deleted. And 20K users can vote to delete answers with negative scores.

Comment: yes. Your flag = 1 flag. It means someone reviewed Your flag. There are like I said 4(or 5) more to go in order to have the question deleted.

Comment: @mehow the act of deleting cause all pending flags on the post to be deemed helpful, but since it wasn't done by a moderator it probably caused the specific scenario where the user can't flag again. The OP here is 20K on Stack Overflow thus can cast "full scale" delete vote.

Comment: @mehow The normal process doesn't quite work like that. A flag eventually finds its way to a moderator, whom can then delete the post and mark the flag as helpful. Only a single flag is needed. Alternatively, if a post is flagged like 5 times, it just gets deleted without moderator interference (this may just hold for comments and/or spam/offensive flags).

Comment: @Dukeling Ok thanks for explanation I must have misunderstood something here. Ill research that in my free time so I dont talk trash next time :P

Comment: @Dukeling only six spam/offensive flags will auto delete a post. Even 1000 "other" or "low quality" flags won't cause any deletion. That said, if 6 reviewers choose "Recommend deletion" via the review process of a specific post, that post will also be auto deleted. I learned it [only recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184566/152859).

Comment: @Dukeling That's true of "other" flags.  It's not true of VLQ flags.  If the post is deleted such flags are marked as helpful and just cleared; they won't be seen by a moderator.  The flags are not "reopened" if the post is undeleted.  The flag just went away, period.