# Add "delete" event when post is deleted via the low quality review process

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-answers, low-quality-posts, revisions-list

After asking [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184566/what-can-cause-an-answer-to-get-deleted-without-information-about-who-actually-d) what can cause an answer to get deleted without any information who deleted it any why, I learned that when 6 users vote "Recommend Deletion" in the low quality review process, the post is indeed deleted but it does not add actual delete "event" to the post revisions.

For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21695052/447356) was deleted via [this review process](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4027766) and now its [revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21695052/revisions) looks like this:

> [image]

Can you please add some indication the post is deleted in the revisions list?

I suggest something like:

> deleted via low quality review

Where the "low quality review" is a link to the relevant review item.

Comment: I assume it would be marked as "deleted by Community"?

Comment: @DennisMeng even just "deleted" as appears in the question page is fine, just as long as there's *something*. That said, changing to something like "deleted via low quality review", linking to the item would be ideal but guess it's a separate request to make. Wait... why not? Adding it to my post.

Comment: Status-completed, it seems: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184568/

Comment: ... but not quite: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233763/

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY true, forgot about it! :)

Comment: @gnat no it is not a duplicate. The first ask "why" this one here asks to change the current behavior.

Comment: Cheers @gnat please also delete the auto generated comment to prevent confusion.

Comment: consider [edit]ing explanation in your comment into answer to let folks like me easier see the difference

Comment: @gnat fair enough, done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184566/what-can-cause-an-answer-to-get-deleted-without-information-about-who-actually-d/184568#184568):

> As of **April 5th, 2014**, all *future* deletions by low-rep users from review will create a special post history entry that includes a link to the review task that resulted in the deletion:
>
> [image: Post Deleted From Review]
>
> Unlike deletions performed by moderators or [trusted users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), post authors can always undelete posts deleted by low-rep users via /review - however, doing so will [raise a flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226993/answers-deleted-via-recommend-deletion-votes-in-review-should-not-be-undeletable/228479#228479) for moderator review.