# Haalp! Really long question titles are a bit borked! You can (no longer) see the bug in action right here

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I just noticed that when a question's title is long enough that it would normally wrap around, it does so a tad late. If the title has a word in the right place, it gets cut off by the background(?!?) of the page.

> [image]

Comment: It wraps, but there's a very specific length where it doesn't..

Comment: It's because you didn't use enough exclamation marks in your question.

Comment: [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226993/answers-deleted-via-recommend-deletion-votes-in-review-should-not-be-undeletable) is another example.

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen yeah, Jin silently fixed some design bugs a week ago. Some quick update or even just proper tag would have been nice, no idea why he doesn't do neither of those.

Comment: -1 improper title. "Haalp!" --> "EEEEEK!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed like a year and a half ago (June 2014).

Comment: +1 what's the future like? (is an example of a comment that will not age well)

Comment: @Pops Were you trying to subtly imply that I should include a date?

Comment: No, I thought there was a decent chance you would earn the Living in the Future hat for this post.

Comment: @Pops Ah, right. That was actually the motivation for posting this answer (though it is nice to be able to accept an answer on this question).

Answer (score 10):

Looks like someone messed up on the padding for the `#question-header` rule. It is currently set to `padding: 20px`, which puts 20px of padding on all four sides. Anyone who knows CSS also knows that by default the padding is not included in the width of the box, so the *actual* width of the box ends up being 40px wider than the page itself, causing 40px of space to the right side (20px of which would always be empty, or the right padding) that will always be cut off if text is present in that area, due to display properties on the ancestor elements.

I'm not exactly sure why they need padding on the left and right sides, and it looks rather silly with that padding there. It seems like that's where the actual mistake is. I think it's supposed to be `padding: 20px 0` which would add padding to the top and bottom, but not the sides.

Comment: There's just too much padding. Everywhere.

Comment: Alternatively, setting `width: auto` on the header would at least make it adapt to the available space, properly excluding the padding.