# On sites with new responsive theme, word wrap on long titles breaks in the middle of a word

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, responsive-design

For sites that have the new responsive theme enabled, where the "Ask Question" button is in line with the question title on question pages, the word wrap on long titles is not working correctly.  It will break a word across two lines.  Here is an [example](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/48073/10997) from Personal Finance and Money:

Maximum width, left nav hidden:
[image: example1]

Narrow width:
[image: example2]

This is also happening on beta sites.  Here is an [example](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3582/1723) on Sports:

[image: example3]

These screenshots were all taken on Firefox, but I am seeing the same problems in Chrome and Internet Explorer.

One more example:
[image: recursive example]

Comment: [Reproduced on SFF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5YEG.png), Firefox 63, Windows 10

Comment: Amusingly, this question itself demonstrates the problem. "middle" gets broken on my screen.

Comment: (For reference, the CSS to solve this is `word-break: break-word;`)

Comment: I noticed this issue on RPG.SE as well.

Comment: [Reported in the relevant meta Q&A there](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8574/33569)

Comment: I believe it is related to the fix for [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375101/another-bug-in-the-profile-page-questions-answers-list-i-will-make-this-tit). It seems as if this is an unintended consequence. At the very least, words should be hyphenated when they wrap.

Comment: `word-break: break-word` is not standard and not supported in Firefox yet. Might be better to switch to `hyphens: auto`?

Comment: Reported on Meta.SO: [Please break titles on words, not letters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376921/4642212).

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4823/long-question-titles-have-words-broken-up-by-the-ask-question-button

Comment: @Jenayah That one's just a case of Stack Exchange deciding that some English spellings are silly.

Comment: [Did title wrapping change? What is *El ectron?*](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1105/12102)

Comment: Reproduced on Opera, Windows 10 as well, on this very question.

Comment: also [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229903/haalp-really-long-question-titles-are-a-bit-borked-you-can-no-longer-see-the) and here [The new profile shouldn't mistakenly imply that you can earn the Informed bad//..](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258179/the-new-profile-shouldnt-mistakenly-imply-that-you-can-earn-the-informed-badge)

Comment: Break happens [even responsiveness is off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318795/339911) via link in the footer

Comment: That is just a side effect of the CSS rules they chose on purpose, so I don't think it can be considered a bug. Changed to feature request since it's asking to change the design.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I’m confident that the fine folks at SE did not intend this behavior, and that this is a bug. I have reverted the tag back to “bug,” as this is a problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: The same on Meta Stack Overflow, *[Please break titles on words, not letters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376921/please-break-titles-on-words-not-letters)*.

Comment: It's absolutely a bug, that was unfortunately introduced Wednesday before the holiday. We're looking into it! It doesn't even require particularly long titles if you're viewing the full site on mobile. Sorry for the delay!

Comment: This issue still persists https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14777/question-title-doesnt-wrap-properly?noredirect=1#comment43237_14777

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We’re breaking lines less aggressively now. This is a bugfix of a bugfix. No good deed goes unpunished

Comment: The bug is not fixed yet.

Comment: How long before we see this fixed?  I've tried clearing my browser cache, but I am still seeing the problem.

Comment: It'll go out in the next build, y'all. It's Sunday night after a major American holiday.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog It looks fixed to me now.

Comment: @AaronShekey According to https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2390#issuecomment-398568426, `overflow-wrap: break-word` will supersede `word-break: break-word` in the future, so I'm unsure why you didn't implement my full suggestion. :)

Comment: @Cœur In practice, `overflow-wrap: break-word` wasn't working in Safari. We use atomic CSS classes, so swapping in the future for `.ow-break-word` will be trivial.

Answer (score 10):

Suggested CSS fix for Stack Exchange webmasters:

Replace all instances of your current class (in stacks.css):

```
.wb-break-all {
    word-break: break-all !important;
}
```

With a human-friendly class:

```
.wb-overflow-wrap: {
    word-break: break-word !important;
    overflow-wrap: break-word !important;
}
```

This way you'll never have overflow (that was the intent, right?) and the wrap will always be on words, not on characters.

<sub>ps: last time I did some CSS was [fifteen years ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20030707042302/http://unicode.coeurlumiere.com:80/), so forgive me if my suggestion is imperfect.</sub>

Comment: [This does not work on Firefox, IE and mobile Edge](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break#Browser_compatibility). It seems there is [a discussion at W3C](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2390) on whether `break-word` should be removed from the spec.

Comment: @DidierL see the line with [`overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap), it should work for any browser.