# Don’t break words in the title

Tags: feature-request, title

I recently noticed that words are broken/split for [long titles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51340237/3240681), e.g.:

- responsiveness enabled

> [image: ed]

- responsiveness disabled

> [image: s]

Could you please not break words in the question title?