# Can anyone tell my why my answer was deleted?

Tags: discussion

I answered the question posted here:

[Angular directive templateURL not being loaded. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27391254/angular-directive-templateurl-not-being-loaded-why/27391411#27391411)

There was only 1 possible solution to the question.  My answer was the first answer to the question.  My answer correctly contained the only possible solution to the question.  A moderator deleted my answer.

Comment: This should be asked on Meta Stack Overflow

Comment: Had you considered trying to explain what the two lines of code in your answer even meant? You know, rather than typing a bunch of dots.

Comment: @TravisJ, The top of this page says Meta.

Comment: @animuson, Can you explain your reply?  What does "Had" mean?  What does "you" mean?  What does "considered" mean?  If you don't understand the language being discussed, then you shouldn't expect to understand the answer.

Comment: @7stud: Yes, but this is Meta Stack Exchange, the Meta for the entire Stack Exchange network, not just for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Quite simply: Your answer was auto-flagged by the system for being low quality. At first glance, it is not *at all* apparent how your answer is actually an answer, and the fact that you used a line of dots to bypass the minimum character requirement makes it jump out at everyone as "PLEASE DELETE ME!!!" All I can say is try typing a better answer if you don't want it deleted.

Comment: @animuson, The quality of an answer does not in anyway correlate to its length.

Comment: But it's a strong indicator, and that's why the system flags it. So users can *review* whether it's a quality answer or not. I'd agree with the flag - that's a terrible quality answer. I'll note that the other person had no problem explaining that they *named the property incorrectly* and it needed to be changed from one to the other. Is it really so hard to include that and have your answer make sense (again, rather than typing a bunch of dots that explain nothing)?

Comment: @animuson,  In my opinion, the quality of an answer should be judged by it's ability to convey what is wrong to the person who posted the question.  When I posted the correct property name directly underneath the incorrect property name, it allowed the op to see precisely what was wrong.

Comment: @7stud That's a *very poor* means of trying to communicate that information.  So poor that almost all of the people (of which there have been quite a few now) all didn't understand that it was an answer, that's how poorly it's managed to convey that information.

Comment: @7stud: Nobody upvoted it, the person who asked the question didn’t accept it, and didn’t comment indicating approval of it. “It allowed the OP to see precisely what was wrong”? There’s no indication that they actually found it helpful, and I wouldn’t be surprised if they found it as unclear as we did.

Comment: I did understand it was an answer, but a very poor one. Just throwing code back at OP without any hint of attempt to explain is bad.

Comment: **That's a very poor means of trying to communicate that information**  I think it was the BEST way to communicate the information.  Why should you have the right to say otherwise?   Why shouldn't the op be allowed to judge for themselves?  Why should a moderator delete any answers?

Comment: @7stud Besides what animuson has already stated, you purposely added characters to evade the character limit - between that and the low quality of the answer I deleted it. Had you formed an actual answer instead of using junk characters to evade the limit, I probably would have been more inclined to keep it around.

Comment: @7stud your answer was considered to be poor, it was auto-flagged, then deleted - being sarcastic about it and arguing about it will not get you your own way. Move on.

Answer (score 14):

It was deleted from the low quality posts queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6437760

It apparently wasn't self explanatory enough for the 6 people who reviewed it to approve, so it got deleted by vote.

And after you undeleted it yourself, the answer wasn't self-explanatory enough for the mod either.

Maybe if you left a more verbose answer, it would not have been deleted.

It can be as simple as this:

> Change `templateURL` to `templateUrl`.

Comment: The user then undeleted it, and a mod deleted it again.

Comment: @Servy is correct and [this isn't a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226993/answers-deleted-via-recommend-deletion-votes-in-review-should-not-be-undeletable). (the mod followed the auto raised flag)

Comment: Maybe I was going to edit my answer when I had more time?  Maybe I was waiting for a moderator to edit my post to make it acceptable?  I see people post answers in pig english all the time that are nearly unintelligible, and moderators rewrite the whole answer--before points have been awarded. Why wasn't my post given that chance?

Comment: **It apparently wasn't self explanatory enough for the 6 people who reviewed it to approve, so it got deleted by vote.**  Which of those 6 people programs in angularJS?  Should a moderator who doesn't understand a technology even be allowed to vote on a post?

Comment: @7stud yes, they should be allowed to vote on a post.  Your target audience isn't experts at angularJS, at least not on the question in which you posted.  Your target audience is beginners.  

And no special expertise with angular should affect the ability of someone to discern that the answer was about the OP making a typo.

Comment: @7stud You had a chance to improve your answer so that wouldn't get deleted again, and you declined to do so.  It wouldn't have been that hard.  Just look at the sample I gave you

Comment: @SamIam, First of all a typo is when you mean to type one thing and you type another thing.  The op did not make a typo--they meant to type "templateURL".  Secondly, anyone who says they couldn't understand my answer--after reading the question--is being disingenuous (yes, I am calling them liars).  Lastly, if the op had been allowed to read my answer, I am positive they would have known what they did wrong.  In my opinion, moderators should not be judging the quality of an answer--that is for the community to decide.

Comment: @SamIam, About your sample answer: putting almost identical words in the same sentence does not immediately highlight their differences.  However, when you put one word under the other word, it is very easy to compare the words character by character, and easily identify the differences, so I think your answer is LESS clear than my answer.

Comment: @7stud My sample answer is a complete sentence.  Complete sentences are generally how English speakers communicate.  It has a verb:  "Change".  It has a subject:  "templateURL".  It has an object:  "templateUrl".  People don't have to guess what it means because it is in plain English

Comment: @7stud Well, then at least subsitute those friggin' useless dots by an *actual explanation*, oh my!

Comment: **Change templateURL to templateUrl**. _My sample answer is a complete sentence. Complete sentences are generally how English speakers communicate. It has a verb: "Change". It has a subject: "templateURL". It has an object: "templateUrl"._