# Don't automatically clear the disputed low quality flags when a post is deleted and undeleted by the owner

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools

When a post is deleted by the review and the post owner undeletes the answer, it [automatically generates a disputed low quality review - Post was undeleted by the author flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317988/4099593), and has a nice bold marking  **♦ PostDeletedFromReview** in the side bar.

However this flag is cleared when the author deletes the post and undeletes it, [which is what happened here (SO 10k+ only)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47909367/revisions):

[image: screenshot]

This particular action isn't that helpful, because users can undelete their review-deleted answers without leaving a trace, by undeleting it, deleting it again, and undeleting it again.

Can we please leave or re-trigger the disputed low quality review flag whenever a user deletes and undeletes their post *after* they have undeleted a review deleted post?

Comment: what about posts that were edited by author after deletion, does it make better sense to clear this flag or keep it for these? If memory serves in my own (limited) experience most such edits sufficiently improve things. Wrt clearing flag on posts that were shaken off by this trick without edits I totally agree, it is really dumb of a system to clear flags in this case (and I have a feeling that some abusers have already learned to use this design mistake to their advantage)

Comment: erm, nope @gnat. I would certainly prefer that the flag stay. This would help to clean up the leftover review comments. Also, in many of the cases which I've seen, the users have undeleted and edited it to add "I can't comment, so adding this as answer". (In one particular case, a user edited an MCVE of the error. If that was posted as a question, it'd have been well received).

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining. Point about cleaning up obsolete comments looks very well taken - I recall now that most of improving edits I've seen were at link-only answers and these indeed frequently leave outdated comments

Comment: That reminds me of another thing, @gnat. Few users directly copy-paste the entire chunk of text from the link to the answer. Those need to be deleted as well.

Comment: This should be considered a bug, but the real cause is the feechur that [a single user can override multiple reviewers' decisions in the first place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479/). You should only get unilateral undelete if you were the unilateral deleter.

Comment: I don't think so @JoshCaswell because I've seen it too many times how users delete their answers prior to review completion (probably being scared by review comments or downvotes). Later they undelete (maybe just to see what happens) and all flags are shaken off and post hangs unattended. That's a case of unilateral deletion / undeletion but I doubt that it's OK that system lets it go unnoticed

Comment: I don't disagree with that, @gnat.

Comment: @gnat Bounties are a better way to provide *community* input, not to get a response from the team. Pinging a staff member in chat or contacting SE is a better way to get a team response.

Comment: [I think I know a bit about bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165773/gnat?tab=bounties&sort=offered "'335 Offered bounties for 32,700 reputation'") @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog