# What happens when a question in the Close Votes review queue is self-deleted (and undeleted)?

Tags: feature-request, support, review, vote-to-close, deleted-posts

I had flagged [this now-deleted question on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/8588/placeholder-stackitup-question) because it appeared to be a duplicate of [this question by the same author](https://stackapps.com/questions/8586/placeholder-this-question-is-for-demo-purposes-only). The author has now removed their own 'duplicate' question, but my flag is still pending:

[image]

I suspect (based on the IDs of review queue items) that [this](https://stackapps.com/review/close/6271) is the corresponding Close Votes review queue item, but I lack privileges to see it. It looks like to have been invalidated – my flag will age away, but that's not a real problem.

I'm wondering what happens when the author decides to *undelete* their question. This situation isn't covered in [Question flags, queues, edits, roomba, community♦, how does this actually work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252048/295232) or [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/295232).

Will this undeletion reactivate the review queue item, or would this be a way for users to cheat their way around the closing procedures? In that case, consider this a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) / [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report to fix this one way or another; a question that gets undeleted while it has pending close flags/votes should re-enter the Close Votes review queue.

Comment: IIRC, I believe I've previously seen this happen on SO and that the question is not placed back in the CV review queue. However, I'd prefer to see an official response. Alternately, we could do some testing on Stack Apps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is a review task marked "completed"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164288/when-is-a-review-task-marked-completed)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thanks, that might answer the [support] part (not sure if self-deletions are handled differently; if a moderator undeletes a question, I'm OK with it not re-entering the close vote review queue). The [feature-request] remains.

Comment: The deletion part causes [this message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226993/answers-deleted-via-recommend-deletion-votes-in-review-should-not-be-undeletable/228479#comment747704_227112), so the undeletion *ought to* offer a similar message relating to the undeletion, apparently the flags will be cleared (and one for the moderators added); no mention of it regaining it's spot in the queue. So this question is a close duplicate, with a complete answer missing there (and "support", tag here).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/282094)

Comment: @Rob c'mon - have you *read* that answer? It doesn't even mention the Close Votes review queue.