# Posts deleted by the community (from the low-quality review queue) don't show why they were deleted

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, deleted-posts

If a post is deleted by its owner, it shows the status "deleted by owner".  If it's deleted by users casting delete votes, it shows "deleted by (names)".  If it's deleted through spam or offensive flags, it shows "deleted by Community".  But if it's deleted from the low-quality review queue, it just says "deleted".  [This seems to be by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184568/162102).

[image: screen shot, with obligatory red freehand circle]

I saw one of these today and was puzzled.  Because I'm a moderator on the site where I saw it, I could look at the timeline and see how it happened.  But non-moderator 10k users can't.  I know that the review will show up in the revision history for the post, but if there haven't been any edits -- a common occurrence on the deleted LQ posts I've seen -- then you have to know how to manually construct the URL to see the revisions.

Could these deletions say "deleted by Community" like spam/offensive ones do?  (I think naming the six voters would create confusion, but we don't need names -- just a hint that this wasn't a moderator action or a bug.)

Comment: Cheers, obsolete comments cleared. Anyway, I would have  the "deleted" link to the review item, this will give all the needed info in one click.

Comment: [Is this status-completed now?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184568/259867)

Comment: No, it's not status-completed -- the question already says that you *can* dig into the revisions but explains why that's not ideal.

Comment: Too late to reply, user already deleted. (However you can still find him in the Tavern ;)) - anyway, a while ago, they started to add link to review item in the auto added comments, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269314/152859) for example. While still not ideal, it's better than before.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was answering for "the record", not for the deleted user. :-)  That is, in case somebody else comes along, sees that comment, and thinks to mark this status-completed, I wanted to explain why it's not.  The new review links in the auto-comments should help with this; thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This was implemented by Konamiman on October 26, 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267485/why-was-that-deleted-provide-better-information-for-deletions-from-review/314201#314201). You now see the reviewer's names on an answer deleted from review:

> [image: "deleted from review [time] by [reviewers]"]

It appears that the reviewers listed there are sorted in user ID order, so users whose accounts are older will appear before users whose accounts are newer.