# Why was that deleted? Provide better information for deletions from review

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts, deleted-posts

When questions are deleted by the Community user, they say "deleted by Community" and now also have a reason:

[image: question deleted by Roomba]

When any post is deleted as spam or offensive it also attributes the deletion (but doesn't give the reason):

[image: deleted as spam]

And if it's deleted by the owner we're told that:<sup>1</sup>

[image: answer deleted by owner]

But if, instead, it's deleted from the low-quality review queue, we instead get this:

[image: review deletion]

I think I've now answered multiple questions about this on every single site I moderate, and probably some others besides.  I understand that it would be confusing to list the six people who voted from the queue (some of whom can only *recommend* deletion, not having the privilege), but that's ok -- we don't identify spam-flaggers either.

Could posts deleted from review queues say "deleted by Community from review" or something similar?

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, *answers* deleted by the owner say "deleted by owner".  For some reason, *questions* deleted by the owner say "deleted by (user name)".  I don't really care; I'm just anticipating a question.

Comment: In spam/offensive case one doesn't need a reason to be stated in the notice; it's prominently displayed in post body. Agree with "deleted yesterday" being unclear.

Comment: @MiceElf right -- the absence of a deletion reason for the spam case wasn't a complaint, just an attempt to describe the behavior.  Moderators are the only ones who can't tell at a glance that it was deleted from flags.

Comment: Agreed, worth to mention that in the beginning there wasn't even any mention of this in the revisions, until [I asked to add such a thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220465/add-delete-event-when-post-is-deleted-via-the-low-quality-review-process).

Comment: Anyhow, I would go with "deleted from review", where "review" would link to the review item.

Comment: This is a bit more difficult than we hoped. We still want to do it, but there isn't bandwidth to do *right this moment*.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco thanks for the update.  Didn't realize it was hard. :-(  Someday, I hope!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was implemented by Konamiman on October 26th, 2016.

### Spam or Rude/abusive

[image: deleted as spam or offensive Nov 24 '13 at 17:07 by Community]

### Deleted by recommendation from review

[image: deleted from review Jan 13 '15 at 13:16 by laalto, Lundin, Jerodev, James Webster, nkjt, Sam]