# If a post is deleted and undeleted by a mod, then later deleted from review, the deletion is misattributed to the moderator instead of reviewers

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, deleted-answers, low-quality-posts

This is a pretty small edge case, but hey, it's a bug.

The post I'm looking at is [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33638/queen-of-all-riddles/33660#33660). It was deleted by me, then undeleted by me (a few hours before the review) after I decided it would be better to leave it up to reviewers and/or follow up after they'd had a chance to edit their answer.

Seven hours later, it was deleted via six Delete selections from review. However, instead of showing ["deleted X hour(s) ago"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe17G.png) like I'd expect (taken from another random LQP review), it instead shows ["deleted by Emrakul X hour(s) ago"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJHaS.png) (the post in question).

Except I didn't delete it (the second time). It was deleted [from review](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/20250).

Again, sort of a small thing, and I doubt it'll ever create a serious issue, but I felt like reporting it anyway.

Comment: Can't see for myself, what do the revisions show? Anything weird in there?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It doesn't look like the answer was ever revised. Mod timeline shows basically the same thing: deleted by mod, undeleted by mod, a few hours later deleted from review.

Comment: This goes back to review-deletions being *special* (as in, not recording the same history type and not requiring multiple voters or a moderator to undelete). See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267485/why-was-that-deleted-provide-better-information-for-deletions-from-review

Comment: @Shog9 so should we mark this as duplicate? (as fixing that other one will also fix this one?)

Comment: Don't care; just wanted them cross-linked. I guess strictly-speaking, this is a bug while that isn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was fixed as part of [the changes needed to correctly attribute deletion from review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267485/why-was-that-deleted-provide-better-information-for-deletions-from-review/314201#314201).

Comment: It looks like that change introduced another edge case, in the [exact opposite case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336092/answers-deleted-from-review-then-undeleted-then-re-deleted-by-a-moderator-stil).