# Answers deleted via review, then undeleted, then re-deleted by a moderator still show as "deleted via review"

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, post-notices

This is the exact opposite of [this prior bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279861/if-a-post-is-deleted-and-undeleted-by-a-mod-then-later-deleted-from-review-the).

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336012/377214) was deleted via review, as a result of [six users recommending deletion from the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/67925). It was subsequently undeleted by its author, then a moderator later re-deleted it. However, on the post itself, it shows as "deleted via review" with the same timestamp as the moderator deletion, even though it wasn't actually deleted via review at the time:

[image: deleted "from review" 13 hours ago]

(This screenshot was taken before the new post notices rolled out in November 2019, but it's still an issue with that form.)

Here's a screenshot of the revision history:

[image: Deleted from review, then undeleted by author, then re-deleted by a moderator 13 hours ago]

This also can result in strange "bugs" where when normal users attempt to vote to undelete the post, they'll receive an error message saying that a moderator deleted it, which is extremely confusing since according to the notice, it was "deleted via review", not by a moderator. Only if one looks at the post's history is it clear that the message is actually correct.

*Technical details follow:*

As far as I can tell, the system normally determines which user to indicate as the one who deleted the post on the post itself by tracking down which user was attributed to the last post deletion event. Also, deletions from review are [essentially attributed to *no one*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279861/if-a-post-is-deleted-and-undeleted-by-a-mod-then-later-deleted-from-review-the#comment907294_279861), with no corresponding "post deleted" event (the "post deleted from review" event is entirely separate). This led to the [opposite bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279861/if-a-post-is-deleted-and-undeleted-by-a-mod-then-later-deleted-from-review-the) where when a moderator deleted and undeleted a post that was later deleted from review, it incorrectly attributed the deletion to the moderator (as the last "post deleted" event was attributed to the moderator).

Later, however, the system was changed to explicitly check for the case where a post was deleted from review, and change the deletion notice accordingly. It appears that if the post was deleted from review at any point, that logic will *always* show the review notice, even though the most current deletion was actually performed not through review (e.g. by a mod, the owner, three trusted users, the Community user, etc.).

Can we fix it so that the logic to change the deletion notice to the "review" one doesn't kick in if there's another "post deleted" event that takes place after the "post deleted from review" event?

**Update:** This still continues to be an issue with the new post notices.

Comment: Related, likely the same bug but I'm not sure: [Post undeleted and converted to comment still shows as being deleted from review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290623/post-undeleted-and-converted-to-comment-still-shows-as-being-deleted-from-review)

Comment: I don't see this as a bug. The moderator is merely sustaining the reviewers' deletion.

Comment: @CodyGray Even if that's the case, it's *not* the case that the post was deleted from review 13 hours ago. It was deleted from review 20 hours ago, then the deletion was later sustained by a moderator 13 hours ago. With your interpretation, it should still say "20 hours ago". (Times are relative to when I took the screenshots.)